# Doesnt save values anymore when it has foreign key but when I delete the foreign key constraint, It does save. what could be the problem?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

At first I was able to save values into the table called "tbl_spareparts" but when i added a foreign key it doesnt save anymore.

tbl_spareparts(unit_id) is referenced to tbl_unitdescription(id).

code is for dynamic fields where you can add more input boxes or remove them.

here is my insert code:

```
     <?php
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "incidentreport");

   if(isset($_POST['submit_data'])) {
   $description = $_POST['description'];
   $qty = $_POST['qty'];
                                          

   foreach ($description as $key => $value) {
   $save = "INSERT INTO tbl_spareparts(unit_id,description,qty) VALUES ('','".$value."', '".$qty[$key]."')";
    $query =    mysqli_query($connect, $save);
      }

     }


    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The empty string '' is not equivalent to NULL in mySql.
With your insert you try to put the `''` value into the colum and it, probably, doesn't reference any id of the `tbl_unitdescription` table.

If the `unit_id` column is nullable try with

```
$save = "INSERT INTO tbl_spareparts(unit_id,description,qty) VALUES (NULL,'".$value."', '".$qty[$key]."')";
```

or insert an `unit_id` value which references an existing id in a row in the `tbl_unitdescription` table (which works in any case).